# Can't get the script to consolidate data side-by-side

Tags: vba, excel

I'd really appreciate if someone helped me with this problem. Admittedly, I'm very new to all this so please go easy on me.
I have a code that consolidates data from a large number of workbooks to a single master worksheet. I'm targeting same cells from different workbooks (for example A5 from all workbooks and pasting them into my worksheet as a column under cell A1, and A13 from workbooks under B1 column, etc). But when I change the code at this line from "A" to "B"  and run it again to get other column of data from the workbooks:

```
Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(9, 1)

Set Dest = shtDest.Range("B" & 
shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
```

it goes diagonally to the next column AND the next row. e.g. when A1 to A11 is finished, it starts pasting to B12 (diagonally) in the destination worksheet, rather than starting from B1 (side-by-side).

Here is the entire code:

```
Sub MergeFiles()
    Dim path As String, ThisWB As String, lngFilecounter As Long
    Dim wbDest As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Filename As String, Wkb As Workbook
    Dim CopyRng As Range, Dest As Range
    Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer

    RowofCopySheet = 1 'Row to start on in the sheets you are copying from

    ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    path = "C:\batch"

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Filename = Dir(path & "\*.csv", vbNormal)
    If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Do Until Filename = vbNullString
        If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
            Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 1)
            Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & 
shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
            CopyRng.Copy Dest
            Wkb.Close False
        End If

        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    Range("A1").Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you deciding when it needs to switch to column B? You will need to swop over to using something like   Set Dest = shtDest.Range("B" & shtDest.Cells(shtDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1) and that point (although if that = 1 then you want to not do the + 1

Comment: It worked! Can't thank you enough @QHarr

Comment: I forgot to change the second "A" to "B". Now it is pasting side-by-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & 
shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
```

to this

```
Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.Cells(shtDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
```

And make sure when running for second time to use:

```
Set Dest = shtDest.Range("B" & shtDest.Cells(shtDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
```

Though if

```
shtDest.Cells(shtDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  = 1
```

OR

```
shtDest.Cells(shtDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row  = 1
```

you don't want to add the + 1 as you are at the first row for pasting.

Comment: Feeling a strong sense of gratitude towards you. Thanks a million!